# NoSql and Data-Warehouse

Tags: nosql, data-warehouse

What are the relations between NoSql and Data-Warehouse technologies/theories?

What concepts they share?

What are the basic differences between them?

How do you think each could be benefits/enriches from the other?

I think your ideas should be helpful for the future of both technologies.

**UPDATE**:

Some useful links:

- [Integrating NoSQL in the Data Warehouse](http://smartdatacollective.com/barry-devlin/33172/integrating-nosql-data-warehouse)
- [NoSQL and Data Warehousing](http://ayende.com/blog/4552/nosql-and-data-warehousing)
- [Are You Ready for Big Data?](http://www.infogain.com/company/perspective-big-data.jsp)

**2nd UPDATE:**

- [MongoDB, BI and Non-Relational Databases](http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/6715306643/mongodb-bi-and-non-relational-databases)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Data Warehouses have very little in common with NoSQL - the main similarity is that any two data warehouses can have very different philosopohies or conventions just like any two NoSQL systems can be nearly unrelated.

The only concept they share is that they are both used to analyze large amounts of data.

NoSQL solutions usually manage relatively limited schemas with large cardinality in few entities, while data warehouses typically have lots of facts and dimensions (in a dimensional model) or lots of entities in a 3NF model.  DW systems usually manage multiple lines of business and attempt to combine that data.

DW systems typically have reporting abilities in SQL which allows you to access all the data in a standard way.  NoSQL systems are typically more code-based - for instance Map/Reduce.

Comment: I think you're right, (http://java.dzone.com/news/nosql-and-data-warehousing) Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

Ayende Rahien explain it well in his blog:

http://ayende.com/blog/4552/nosql-and-data-warehousing

"For data warehousing, I think that the relational / OLAP world has significant advantages, mostly because in many BI scenarios, you want to allow the users to explore the data, which is easy with the SQL toolset, and harder with NoSQL solutions. But when you get too large (and large in OLAP scenarios is really large), you might want to consider limiting the users’ options and going with a NoSQL solution tailor to what they need."

Answer (score 5):

My favorite quote from the deck:
"document-databases are far superior to relational databases for business intelligence cases. Not only that, but mongoDB and some common sense lets you replace multimillion dollar IBM-level enterprise solutions with open-source awesomeness. All this in a rapid, agile way."
http://www.10gen.com/presentations/mongodc-2011/time-series-data-storage-mongodb

Also:
"Map/Reduce may yet be your killer app that can be the panacea for all your Business Intelligence ailments. This is very serious stuff. If Google has bet its house on it and has made this the foundation for their search technology, then you better believe that this is very strong medicine."
http://www.infogain.com/company/perspective-big-data.jsp

Answer (score 0):

Data warehouse system are generally used for quick reporting to management and NoSql system are generally for handle very large data for map reduction

Data warehouse uses relational database while NoSql  use non relational database.

NoSql database are faster than data warehouse.

We use SQL in data warehouse but we need not require SQL for manipulating data in NoSql

Data warehouse consists of dimension and fact while NoSql are consist limited schema.