# Advise for NoSQL starter

Tags: nosql

I am planning to start learning NoSQL. 
I have started with the book "Professional NoSQL". 
In the book there are examples using CouchDB,Cassandra,MongoDB etc.
My doubt is 
should i install all the different flavors to learn the NoSQL fully?
for a person starting to learn NoSQL which NoSQL DB is preferred to start with?

Answer (score 4):

This question has effectively already been answered on StackOverflow. Below are some links to previous dicsussions with links to other blogs and Wikipedia -

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883326/nosql-databases

[NoSql and Data-Warehouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684462/nosql-and-data-warehouse)

The nosql wikipedia page has loads of information and is a great place to start - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL.

All the nosql vendors have tutorials on their websites - just google the "mongodb tutorial" or "couchdb tutorial" etc.

Only you can decide which no sql db suits you - it depends on your application and data and I guess your own comfort with the solution from a technical perspective.

Answer (score 2):

I think `redis` is popular and easy enough to get start with.